# When plotting with sns/seaborn, it just shows 1 chunk of graph

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

**What I want to achieve is something similar to this:**
[image: what i want to achieve]

**This is the code I added:**

```
from pandas import *
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
from math import *

import numpy as num
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
%matplotlib inline

import seaborn as sns

import statistics

users = pd.read_table("/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/Datasets/users.dat",sep="::",names=['UserID','Gender','Age','Occupation','ZipCode'],encoding='latin-1')

users['Age'].value_counts()
sns.countplot(users["Age"])
```

**And this is what I ended up with instead:**
[image: this is what i ended up recieving]

I tried using a different file to make sure that the data was correct, I also tried making sure that I didn't misspell anything incorrectly and tried single quotation marks just to get the same result. IDK what's the cause of the problem, unless its the data itself.

**BTW here's the users file if you're interested:**
https://drive.google.com/file/d/10iF0gKWAX8GfzOTgCrtgUHMjtcqcvv3R/view

Comment: You need `sns.countplot(users, x='Age')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this code, the issue is due to `countplot()` which may be related to the distribution of the data. `Countplot()` visualizes data by counting occurrences in each age group, so if some age groups have very few instances, they might not appear on the plot. To address this, you can arrange the age groups in ascending order and adjust the figure size to ensure the visibility of all age groups on the plot.

Try this code:

```
users = pd.read_table("/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/Datasets/users.dat", sep="::", names=['UserID', 'Gender', 'Age', 'Occupation', 'ZipCode'], encoding='latin-1')
age_counts = users['Age'].value_counts().sort_index()
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
sns.countplot(users["Age"], order=age_counts.index)
plt.show()
```